# Google apps scripts Authorization error "You do not have authorization to perform that action."

Tags: google-apps-script

From short time I mentioned that all new spreadsheet with script when I share it with anybody with edit access they can't access script editor and also they can't run script from added menu by script it always gives error message"You do not have authorization to perform that action." also if they take copy of it the script editor of thier copy is empty

I tried to solve it but no way I have used another account but no way, any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when I wanted to transfer a template to another user and what I did was, took a copy of my spreadsheet and gave edit access to the other user.

The other user then accesses this sheet and takes a copy, but before the user takes a copy the script editor needs to be opened by that user to ensure necessary access is there.

BUT ONE THING YOU NEED TO ENSURE IS THAT BOTH USERS ARE IN THE SAME DOMAIN, OTHERWISE THIS WIL NOT WORK.